Is it haram to act as a prophet Ibrahim
Assalamualaikum,you see,iam making a skit performance for Eid ul adha,it is about the story of the origin of Eid ul adha,so I'm asking if it is haram to act as prophet Ibrahim (as) because his face is not shown mostly
